# Detect coordinates of a wifi ap from an app

Tags: android, wifi, coordinates, android-wifi

I am making an android app. I am connecting the device with one wifi AP. Now I want to get the latitude and the longitude of that AP. Is it possible? My gut feeling says that it should not be permitted (even if possible) due to security concerns. Also, it should depend on the AP's hardware itself as whether it stores it latitude and longitude or not. But to say the least, I have no clue on how to achieve this(is it even achievable?). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you're connecting from wifi then really how many people will be at a much greater lat and long than the device? Why would the device's location not be good enough other than showing them on some kind of wifi ap map? This may be more of a hardware manufacturer thing that they can do with they're own software and ap's. There are other ways like have user go to ap point then use get location button which gets the location the device is at (ap point) then go to another ap and same thing. Store the locations and you have a map with user acceptance.

Comment: One crude way (read accurate to 10-20 meters) is to get the RSSI from the connected wifi AP and convert to distance in meters. Then from the device's current location get Lat, Lng and bearing. Once you have all the three i.e. initial lat-lng, bearing and distance you can find the lat, lng of the wifi AP